# How to reuse locations value of ContextConfiguration annotation in spring tests

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I have a lot of tests with spring. Our application context consists several xml files. Something like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration( locations = {
        "classpath:aaaaa.xml",
        "classpath:bbbbb.xml"})
```

Spring caches the contexts by default, which prevents re-creating the context each time for each tests, which improves performance. To enjoy this feature I have to use in each test exactly the same "locations".

How can I share this kind of annotation between tests? I know that I can create a parent class, which all test can extend. However sometimes I do need to extend an other class. I tried to put the String[] into a constant, but annotations cannot have a constant as value, since it is forbidden.

So the question is how to share a set of spring context xml locations between tests without a parent class?

Answer (score 0):

I have found it out. I have to create a class like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@ImportResource(value = {
        "classpath:aaaaa.xml",
        "classpath:bbbbb.xml"})
public class IntegrationTestConfiguration {
}
```

Then in test classes I have to say:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = IntegrationTestConfiguration.class )
public class MyTest
```

Thats it.

Comment: If we are not using xml configuration,we use class how will we handle it?

Comment: @Import({ 
 ConfigA.class, 
 ConfigB.class,
 ConfigC.class})

Comment: org.springframework.context.annotation.Import annotation